# dependent validation lists from two column dataset

Tags: excel, validation

All of the dependent validation list examples I have seen rely on using several columns, each storing a different data type, then made a named range.

But my data looks like this, where in sheet "DB" across two columns I have a device type and then the device model defined:

```
Type    Model
Switch  2950
Router  2900
Switch  4948
Router  2800
```

I am trying to create a pair of dependent validation columns in sheet "Build" where in A2 if I select Router from the drop-down, my possible options are either 2800 or 2900 for B2. I don't have any code examples because I am really not sure where to start.

The logic would be where value from Build!A2 = values from named range Type, return all values one column over into Build!A3.

Comment: A standard dependent drop-down requires the values you want to sort by each be entered on their own column. So I would need one column for router, one for switch, etc, etc. Makes the data unmanageable when you have a) additional fields for a given row b) a large data set c) frequent updates. I did quite a bit of reading before posting, but couldn't find anything that remotely fit the bill, so there was nothing for me to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using the OFFSET function. It's not perfect since it requires your primary column to always be sorted, but it works.

http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal13.html

The link describes it well, but using my example data above I created a named range TypeStart that is the header column for Type, and a named range for that entire column called TypeColumn. Then on my second sheet where column A is a validation drop-down keyed to Type, column B has this validation List formula below:

```
=OFFSET(TypeStart,MATCH(B2,TypeColumn,0)-1,1,COUNTIF(TypeColumn,B2),1)
```